# Imprimir toda página HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, impressão

Fiz uma simples função para imprimir o conteúdo do meu site ao clicar em um botão, porém ao clicar no botão (ctrl+p) as imagens do site não aparecem, apenas o conteúdo... Apenas aparecendo se o usuário aperta em "Exibir Gráfico de Segundo Plano" na janela de impressão do Google Chrome.

Minha ideia é que o usuário possa imprimir direto do SmartPhone, porém essa opção de habilitar gráficos em segundo plano não aparece nos celulares.

Alguém sabe se existe alguma forma do navegador não entender que as imagens são gráficos em segundo plano ? Existe algum CSS especial que devo colocar no @print que possa configurar isso ?

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Essa imagens são usando a tag <img> ou essas imagens são background-img?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a propriedade [`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust), mas, como informa a documentação, não é uma propriedade padronizada e pode não funcionar em todos os navegadores ou dispositivos.

Testando no Chrome, funcionou, mas no Firefox não. Você pode conferir as compatibilidades no site [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-print-color-adjust):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É preciso ter em mente que o programador/desenvolvedor não tem controle total sobre o navegador, e muitas coisas só ocorrem pela ação direta do usuário. Às vezes é preciso recorrer a outros métodos. No seu caso, você poderia usar outra forma de exibir as imagens, como colocando elas diretamente no HTML de forma *flutuante* sob o conteúdo. Assim não precisaria se preocupar com essa parte de impressão.